# Why should our work inside the container shouldn't modify the content of the container itself?

Tags: docker, containers, virtualization, docker-container, docker-image

I am reading an [article](https://stackify.com/docker-image-vs-container-everything-you-need-to-know/) related to docker images and containers.

It says that a container is an instance of an image. Fair enough. It also says that whenever you make some changes to a container, you should create an image of it which can be used later.

But at the same time it says:

> Your work inside a container shouldn’t modify the container. Like
>   previously mentioned, files that you need to save past the end of a
>   container’s life should be kept in a shared folder. Modifying the
>   contents of a running container eliminates the benefits Docker
>   provides. Because one container might be different from another,
>   suddenly your guarantee that every container will work in every
>   situation is gone.

What I want to know is that, what is the problem with modifying container's contents? Isn't this what containers are for? where we make our own changes and then create an image which will work every time. Even if we are talking about modifying container's content itself and not just adding any additional packages, how will it harm anything since the image created from this container will also have these changes and other containers created from that image will inherit those changes too.

Answer (score 2):

Treat the container filesystem as ephemeral. You can modify it all you want, but when you delete it, the changes you have made are gone.

This is based on a union filesystem, the most popular/recommended being overlay2 in current releases. The overlay filesystem merges together multiple lower layers of the image with an upper layer of the container. Reads will be performed through those layers until a match is found, either in the container or in the image filesystem. Writes and deletes are only performed in the container layer.

So if you install packages, and make other changes, when the container is deleted and recreated from the same image, you are back to the original image state without any of your changes, including a new/empty container layer in the overlay filesystem.

From a software development workflow, you want to package and release your changes to the application binaries and dependencies as new images, and those images should be created with a Dockerfile. Persistent data should be stored in a volume. Configuration should be injected as either a file, environment variable, or CLI parameter. And temp files should ideally be written to a tmpfs unless those files are large. When done this way, it's even possible to make the root FS of a container read-only, eliminating a large portion of attacks that rely on injecting code to run inside of the container filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Docker workflow has two parts.

First you build an image:

1. Check out the relevant source tree from your source control system of choice.
2. If necessary, run some sort of ahead-of-time build process (compile static assets, build a Java `.jar` file, run Webpack, ...).
3. Run `docker build`, which uses the instructions in a `Dockerfile` and the content of the local source tree to produce an image.
4. Optionally `docker push` the resulting image to a Docker repository (Docker Hub, something cloud-hosted, something privately-run).

Then you run a container based off that image:

1. `docker run` the image name from the build phase.  If it's not already on the local system, Docker will pull it from the repository for you.

Note that you don't need the local source tree just to run the image; having the image (or its name in a repository you can reach) is enough.  Similarly, there's no "get a shell" or "start the service" in this workflow, just `docker run` on its own should bring everything up.

(It's helpful in this sense to think of an image the same way you think of a Web browser.  You don't download the Chrome source to run it, and you never "get a shell in" your Web browser; it's almost always precompiled and you don't need access to its source, or if you do, you have a real development environment to work on it.)

Now: imagine there's some critical widespread security vulnerability in some core piece of software that your application is using (OpenSSL has had a couple, for example).  It's prominent enough that all of the Docker base images have already updated.  If you're using this workflow, updating your application is very easy: check out the source tree, update the `FROM` line in the `Dockerfile` to something newer, rebuild, and you're done.

Note that none of this workflow is "make arbitrary changes in a container and commit it".  When you're forced to rebuild the image on a new base, you really don't want to be in a position where the binary you're running in production is something somebody produced by manually editing a container, but they've since left the company and there's no record of what they actually did.

In short: *never* run `docker commit`.  While `docker exec` is a useful debugging tool it shouldn't be part of your core Docker workflow, and if you're routinely running it to set up containers or are thinking of scripting it, it's better to try to move that setup into the ordinary container startup instead.